# Unable to use ufw on ubuntu 20?

Tags: ufw

I am unable to use ufw on ubuntu 20.
It is already installed(apt install shows already the latest version)

When i type ufw  command the output is:
File "/usr/sbin/ufw", line 25, in 
import ufw.frontend
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ufw'

I think the problem is related to multiple versions of python on my pc. python is linked to anaconda python 3.7. I opened all possible python interpreter(for 2.7, 3.7 and 3.8) and tried to import ufw in each. Only in python 3.8 the import is successful.

So ufw exists but i think it is looking to find something in some other locations(probably anaconda folders).

How to correct this?

Comment: Does: `sudo apt reinstall ufw` help?

Comment: Your /usr/bin/python3 should always link to the **default** version for your Ubuntu release (python3.8 for Ubuntu 20.04) - otherwise you are likely to break not just ufw but also apt

Comment: @steeldriver you are correct. Read my answer. I did not read your comment earlier. Could have saved me some time.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

1. First I removed anaconda related directories from my PATH.
2. Then I went to /usr/bin and linked python3 to python3.8(previously it was pointing to anaconda python 3.7). After this I typed python and confirmed python3.8 shell is opening. Then I gave ufw command and it worked normally.

However even after adding back the anaconda related directories the ufw command still worked(But python and python3 command output showed anaconda 3.7). So I think the first step is not required at all.

This solves another problem that I have been facing for a long time(My terminal wont open with Control + ALT +T and the hints I got online was that it is related to python but that time I was not able to solve it). Yesterday it started working with the above changes(I mean only the 2nd step).